# Holding button on moblie

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to make some controls for android mobile phone. Want to make a button that if the player touches and holds he starts to move to the right/left. And If he stops holding it the movement to the side stops.

I have this script for moving by holding the certain key:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Add a forward force
    rb.velocity = new Vector4(0, 0, ForwardForce * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))  // If the player is pressing the "d" key
    {
        // Add a force to the right
        rb.velocity = new Vector4(SidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForwardForce * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.x);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))  // If the player is pressing the "a" key
    {
        // Add a force to the left
        rb.velocity = new Vector4(-SidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForwardForce * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 UI buttons.

1 button for left and 1 for right.

Add event trigger component to each button.

Create a class for the movements, something like:

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

```
 public float speed = 3;

 public void MoveLeft(){
     transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
 }

 public void MoveRight(){
     transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

}

Call it on UpdateSelected and use Pointer Up / Pointer Down event.

Comment: When I call UpdateSelected it keeps the button "pressed" so the script is activated. Basically I cannot stop the movement